ngx-scrollbar RTL mode not working in my Angular project
I am trying to implement RTL (Right-to-Left) support for scrolling using the ngx-scrollbar package in my Angular project. However, the scrollbar does not appear to function correctly in RTL mode.
I installed ngx-scrollbar in my Angular project using:
npm install ngx-scrollbar

I added the following code to my template to enable RTL mode:
<ng-scrollbar buttons [dir]="'rtl'"></ng-scrollbar>

Despite this, the scrollbar does not display correctly in RTL mode. It works fine in LTR (Left-to-Right) mode.
What I’ve Tried

I checked the ngx-scrollbar documentation and confirmed that the dir attribute should enable RTL mode.
I verified that my application supports RTL by setting other elements to dir="rtl", and they display as expected.
I tried using different browsers to rule out browser-specific issues.

stackblitz Demo Link
Environment
Angular: 18.0.0
CDK/Material: 18.0.2
Browser(s): chrome
Operating System (e.g. Windows, macOS, Ubuntu): Window

This is not the way it works, you have two options:
To make a webpage

RTL, add the attribute to the html tag <html dir="rtl">
Or use BidiModule from Angular CDK as in this stackblitz

import { BidiModule } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';

